# JavaScript expand/collapse is not compatibile in MS Edge

Tags: jquery

I have code that works fine with IE but did not work in MS Edge.
In Edge mode, it only expands in the first level but did not work down with the lower level.

```
function MyExpandAll(Mycontainer) {
  Mycontainer.find("details").each(function (){
     if(!$(this).hasClass("MyDiv"))
     $(this).find("summary").slideDown();
  });
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask].   if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: Edge and Chrome are the same software, so please show the HTML

Comment: thx, I used attr() instead of slideDown, and it works now.